# HTTP error 403 if POST is not used

Tags: c#, rest, http

I am trying to send protobuf data via REST from c# winform application. When I use the HTTP request with POST method( as shown in code below) it works perfect and returns "OK" status.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/input");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "xxxyyyzzz"                                 
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\MyProtobuf.proto");
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                MessageBox.Show(myHttpWebResponse .StatusCode.ToString());
myHttpWebResponse .Close();
```

But if I simply want to check if website is alive or not using below code it gives me 403. Forbidden error.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/input");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "xxxyyyzzz";
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
MessageBox.Show(myHttpWebResponse .StatusCode.ToString());
myHttpWebResponse .Close();
```

what could be the possible reason for this error ?

Comment: the page isnt responding to HTTP Get requests

Comment: The reason for the error is that you're sending a GET request to an endpoint that expects a POST request. The 403 does tell you that the site is alive, but I wouldn't recommend using that as a health check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your services serves POST method verb so you must call this service with post method, otherwise you should change your service methods to support get method.

Comment: could you tell me if how can i use POST method as a health check?

Comment: there is no difference between post or get both of them are HTTP verbs , you should only change your method to POST

Comment: If you send a http request your request have header, in post method you can extra data inside request body(it is optional), but in get method you should send extra data via url so you have a limitation on amount of data that you can send